# How to check if the webpage was loaded (without JS)?

Tags: web-applications, web, pageload

How can I check if user has loaded the webpage if the JavaScript is disabled (otherwise I can just send a request on page ready)?

Comment: can you rephrase the question properly??

Comment: You mean, the _server_ wants to know? I guess the server only can find out if the page has finished sending (unless you can observe the associated socket state = not from PHP).

Comment: yes the server wants to know. finished sending is ok, I would only care if the page was fully loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a code in the footer that will make the request, for example:

```
<img src="http://<example.url>/?user_ip=<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']&<any other data needed>" style="display:none" />
```

When a user loads the page, he will ping the example.url and you can store and process further this request.

Comment: note that user_ip is not a unique identifier of a session. I recommend the session ID (and current time to prevent caching).